# angularjs directive that wraps & modifies arbitrary content which includes ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

I am trying to build a directive that:

- wraps arbitrary content
- prepends anchor tags to all 'h4' elements found in that content

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j18KIkEYJ0f8EMurwkO9?p=preview) of what I have so far.

Seems to work fine if wrapped content is static but:

#### entire wrapped content is repeated twice

is my invocation of transcludeFn effectively repeating work that ng-trasclude is doing? Do I need to replace ng-transclude with own impl?

#### 'h4' tags generated by nested ng-repeat are not found by the directive

looks like 'clone' passed to cloneLinkFn in transcludeFn is pre-ng-repeat execution. thought that $compile(clone)(scope) would then produce post-ng-repeat version but that did not work either it seems.

I'd really appreciate a tip or explanation of what I am doing wrong.

thank you,
-nikita

Comment: Do you have a plunker that includes your directive?  Have an idea but would like to test it first.  The plunker you posted doesn't include it.